# How to geometrically transform an image using a matrix

Tags: gimp, image-editing, image-manipulation

How can I transform an image using a custom mathematical 2x2 matrix? To be clear, the math is not the issue; I already have the matrix I want. I just want to know how I can use software to apply the transformation to an image.

I have searched on Google for GIMP plugins (as I know that it uses a 3x3 matrix for perspective, though it won't let me input a 3x3 matrix). There was one called "Mathmap", however it won't work for me due to it supporting an older version of GIMP. I have also searched for programs capable of doing this, but none came up.

The transformation is a geometric transformation not a filter transformation.

If anyone can help me, I greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Most likely you could do that in Octave (depends on image format) https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Loading-and-Saving-Images.html

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/ - to convert images, generally.

Answer (score 2):

There is a GIMP Procedure call, intended to be used from scripts and plug-ins, which can be called directly from the interactive prompts.

Here is an example Python session that retrieves a reference the last image open in GIMP, and
applies a [2, 0, 0,   0, 2, 0,   0, 0, 1]  transform to it.

You can get to the Python console in GIMP in  `filters->python-fu->console`

```
GIMP 2.8.14 Python Console
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jun 25 2014, 10:19:55) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7)]
>>> img = gimp.image_list()[0]
>>> img
<gimp.Image '[Untitled]'>
>>> matrix = [2,0,0, 0,2,0, 0,0,1]
>>> more_parms = [True, TRANSFORM_RESIZE_ADJUST]
>>> drawable = pdb.gimp_drawable_transform_matrix_default(img.layers[0], *(matrix + more_parms))
```

I could find the `gimp_drawable_transform_matrix_default procedure by clicking on the "browse" button at the bottom of the dialog with the Python session, searching for "matrix", and when I found a suitable call, clicking on "apply": that paste the function call on the Python session with mock parameters, I cared to replace.

I then took advantage of Python's "syntax sugar" to pass in sequence elements as individual parameters to a function call - that is what the "*" is for. For it to work, I had to append the 2 extra parameters (interpolation, and clip mode) to the matrix coefficients.

This is in effect the same call as

`pdb.gimp_drawable_transform_matrix_default(img.layers[0], matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], ...., matrix[9], True, TRANSFORM_SIZE_ADJUST)` would be.

Comment: Wow, this is an awesome solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For what it is worth, I'm running a GEGL enabled v2.9 of GIMP installed and updated through    *Ubuntu specific*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp-edge
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp gimp-resynthesizer
```

I wonder if not:
`Menu: Filters > Generic > Convolution Matrix`
... might be what you're after?

Comment: The Convolution Matrix is used to apply filters I believe. I want a geometric transformation.

Comment: Oh, and I don't know about it on Ubuntu, my bad for not tagging windows

Comment: It is present among filters, but it might be the same or similar to what you wish for - well I'm just guessing here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind commercial, there is a nice app that I use for all kinds of image processing tasks: [Batch Image Resizer](https://www.binarymark.com/products/batchimageresizer/default.aspx) (though it's much more than a resizer)

It has a dedicated action exactly for the task you described:

[image]

You can run it from command line, as a GUI, on schedule, or continuously in the background, so it's quite flexible.

They don't seem to offer download on their main page for some reason, but I was able to salvage a link to the free version from elsewhere on their website, hopefully it will work: [BIR Download](https://www.binarymark.com/do.aspx?act=download&pid=2&ref=gallery)